# Find the derivative of: $(f^{-1})'(0)$ with $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\cos(\cos(t))dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives

So, I'm stuck on this question and I'm not really sure what to do, because from research I've found that $f(x)=\int_{a}^{b}\cos(\cos(t))dt$ doesn't actually have an integral, so I don't know how you can derive it, if you don't even know what it actually is, if you get what I'm saying. I think the $(f^{-1})'(0)$ thing might come into it but I'm not sure what it means.

**Question**

Find the following derivative:

$(f^{-1})'(0)$ with $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\cos(\cos(t))dt$

**Note**

In lectures we did prove a theorem/rule pertaining to the inverse of functions and derivatives but I'm not really sure if it can be related because I can't figure it out:

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{(f^{-1})'(f(x))}$

**Additionally**

If you can could you also check if I answered the following question correctly that would be awesome (Not required though)! :)

**Additional Question:**

Find the following derivative:

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{x^3}\sin^3t$ $dt$

**Additonal Working:**

First; $\int_{x}^{x^3}\sin^3t$ $dt=\int_{x}^{x^3}\sin^2t\sin t$ $dt$

Since $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)\implies \int_{x}^{x^3}\sin^2t\sin t$ $dt$ = $\int_{x}^{x^3}(1-\cos^2t)\sin t$ $dt$

Since $\int f(g(x))\times g'(x)$ $dx$ = $\int f(u)$ $du$ when $u=g(x)$

Let $y=\cos(t)$

$\frac{du}{dt}=-\sin(t)$

$du=-\sin(t)\cdot dt$

$\therefore \int_{x}^{x^3}(1-\cos^2(t))\sin(t) dt = \int_{x}^{x^3}u^2-1 du = \int_{x}^{x^3}u^2-\int_{x}^{x^3}1 du = [\frac{1}{3}u^3-u]^{x^3}_{x}=[\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(t))-\cos(t)]_{x}^{x^3} = (\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x^3))-\cos(x^3))-(\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x))-\cos(x))$

$\therefore \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{x^3}\sin^3t$ $dt$ = $\frac{d}{dx}((\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x^3))-\cos(x^3))-(\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x))-\cos(x))) = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{3}\cos^3(x^3)-\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^3)-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{3}\cos^3(x)-\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x) = 3x^2\sin(x^3)-3x^2\sin(x^3)\cos^2(x^3)-\sin(x)+\sin(x)\cos^2(x) = 3x^2\sin^3(x^3)-\sin^3(x)$

$\therefore \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{x^3}\sin^3t$ $dt = 3x^2\sin^3(x^3)-\sin^3(x))$

(Sorry if it's a mess, still getting used to this) Thanks heaps!

Comment: Note that $f'(x)=\cos(\cos(x))$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So would it just be equal to $\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(\cos(x))-\cos(\cos(1)))$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f^{-1}=g$. Then $f(g(x))=x$.

$$ f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$$

$$f'(g(0))g'(0)=1$$

Note that $f(1)=0$. So $g(0)=1$.

$$f'(x)=\cos(\cos x)$$

$$\cos(\cos 1)g'(0)=1$$

$$(
f^{-1})'(0)=\frac{1}{\cos(\cos 1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

From $f(1)=0$ we get $(f^{-1})(0)=\frac{1}{f'(1)}$.

Furthermore: $ f'(x)=\cos(\cos(x))$

Comment: Thanks, just two questions, what about the t=1 and t=x bounds? Also I don't understand why the inverse is involved