# Derivative of an integral using FTC?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm wondering if someone can help me calculate the derivative of the following:

$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_1^x(\cos(\cos(t)) \,dt .$$

I saw this on another question on Stack Exchange but I was unsure how the answers were deriving the result of $\cos(\cos(x))$. Surely, by using the FTC, the derivative of this function would be $\cos(\cos(x)) - \cos(\cos(1))$?

[Find the derivative of: $(f^{-1})'(0)$ with $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\cos(\cos(t))dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261731/find-the-derivative-of-f-10-with-fx-int-1x-cos-costdt) the question in reference by the way. Can anyone help unravel this mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you knew an antiderivative of $F(x)$ of $\cos(\cos x)$.  Then

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^x \cos(\cos t) \; dt = \frac{d}{dx} (F(x)-F(1)) = F'(x)-0$$

because $F(1)$ is a constant.  Finish by noting that $F'(x) = \cos(\cos x).$

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was after. If you wouldn't mind, could you verify if f^-1(x) = y(x), then say f(6) = 12, y(12) = 6? Would the inverse just swap these values?

Comment: Yes, that's how inverses work.